# Converting data showing a range to float in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

data to analyse: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xoWr0SnmZKk6o3iGPan9ud6TeIXrZjpC/view?usp=sharing

I am trying to get the world_rank column to become a float. Since some of the data is a range (152-200) I have tried the following which does not work and causes an error:

```
  #update column name

shanghai_df.rename(columns={'world_rank': 'shanghai_rank'}, inplace=True)
  # replace ranking range to midpoin`t

def mid_rank(rank_string):
    rank = re.sub('=', '', rank_string)
    rank = rank.split('-')
    s = 0
    for each in rank:
        each = float(each)
        s = s + each
    return s/len(rank)

# replace ranking range for shanghai data
shanghai_df['world_rank_tidy'] = shanghai_df['world_rank'].apply(mid_rank)
```

Error message:

```
        NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-603ab3ae72de> in <module>
     10 
     11 # replace ranking range for shanghai data
---> 12 shanghai_df['world_rank_tidy'] = shanghai_df['shanghai_rank'].apply(mid_rank)

/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4354         dtype: float64
   4355         """
-> 4356         return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
   4357 
   4358     def _reduce(

/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply(self)
   1034             return self.apply_str()
   1035 
-> 1036         return self.apply_standard()
   1037 
   1038     def agg(self):

/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
   1090                 # List[Union[Callable[..., Any], str]]]]]"; expected
   1091                 # "Callable[[Any], Any]"
-> 1092                 mapped = lib.map_infer(
   1093                     values,
   1094                     f,  # type: ignore[arg-type]

/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-1-603ab3ae72de> in mid_rank(rank_string)
      1 #Merge the data
      2 def mid_rank(rank_string):
----> 3     rank = re.sub('=', '', rank_string)
      4     rank = rank.split('-')
      5     s = 0

NameError: name 're' is not defined
```

Comment: What error it caused? Please edit your question and put there full traceback.

Comment: The error means that pandas couldn't find the column `"world_rank"`. Is your data loaded correctly?

Comment: add this to the ist of imports ```import re```